# What is the official rule(s) regarding punctuation and end-sentence participles?

Tags: commas, participles, participial-phrases

I tried searching for this, but only received more questions, instead of answers. Recently, I was asked a question about participial phrases and the punctuation that surrounds them. Attempting to answer the question with what I thought to be a cut-and-dry answer, I confused my own self when looking to examples that might present ambiguity. Previously, I had always been taught that, grammatically speaking, we are supposed to put a comma before a participle phrase when it doesn't have its modifying object right next to it. This would prevent ambiguity in most cases. For example, "I jumped over the cow, attempting to get away." versus the counterpart with the comma omitted, meaning something different. However, what are the rules when these participles seem to be complementing? I have a hard time explaining this to non-native speakers who are focusing on the bare structure of sentences. This is the example that they asked me about:

"I went to the concert wearing a gray t-shirt." They asked if a comma should be after "concert", and to be honest, I really don't know. Usually, I would be quick to say it does, as per the grammatical structure and the rules that I've been taught; "I went to the concert, wearing a gray t-shirt." I saw this because the *rule* would prevent ambiguity when present. But then again, would it make sense to leave the comma out when there is no sign of common sense ambiguity. And if so, what role would the participle play in the sentence? I want to say a type of complement.

Comment: @KannE You're right. My bad.

Comment: In _I went to the concert wearing a gray t-shirt_. "Wearing a gray t-shirt" is not a complement but a predicative adjunct that is tightly integrated into the clause, so no comma is necessary. It's predicative because it referes to a predicand, "I", and it's an adjunct because it's a modifier in clause structure.

Comment: @BillJ Where does the rule come in that says it must have a comma before it if it isn't directly following its reference ,"I". There are many cases where the lack of comma could produce ambiguity, even if lacking of common sense leads someone there; "I shot the whale wearing headphones".

Comment: @BillJ A better example-- "I went to the concert representing The Beatles." Two different meanings per the comma usage.

Comment: @AllexKramer Now you're talking about ambiguity. Your question was about what role the participial clause played -- possibly a complement. Perhaps you should edit your question to include ambiguity as a possible factor.

Comment: @BillJ I edited it to try to retain the previous integrity while also adding the new stuff.

I guess, in my mind, I see both sides of this question as going hand in hand.

Comment: @KannE Wow, very good way of putting things. By adding that introductory clause to the sentence, it is easy to see why "wearing a gray t-shirt" is so essential to its meaning that we need to not separate it with a comma. Kudos for that hint!

Interestingly enough, I remember to being taught about participles, in which I was told that they do not technically operate restrictively or non-restrictively, as they are independent of the clauses structure. However, I wonder if this proves that designation wrong. Obviously, "I went to the concert" is a grammatical, but it doesn't have the meaning.

Comment: @KannE I guess those that consider the adjuncts to be separate from the predicate would also be the ones that find themselves engulfed in the “restrictive vs. non-restrictive” talk.

Comment: use punctuation to avoid ambiguity... is any serious reader going to think that a concert is wearing a t-shirt (in the common meaning of the term)? no comma is necessary, but one would not be *wrong:* as stated by better answers and comments on this site, punctuation is a matter of style and not grammar